# Rails before_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a **before_save callback** in the model:

```
self.field2 = self.field1
self.field2['word'] = 'something'
```

I would expect field1 and field2 not to be the same after save, but they are -- field1 becomes same as field2.

Do you know why?

---

**Anwser**

self.field2 = self.field1.clone

Comment: what type are field 1 and field 2?

Comment: If they reference the same object they'll have the same object.

Comment: @Doon they are of type :text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you assign `self.field1` to `self.field2`. They now point to the same object. Then with

```
self.field2['word'] = 'something'
```

You modify the object they both point to.

If you want to copy field1 into field2, try something like `self.field2 = self.field1.clone` instead.